# Dynamically created LinkButton posts back but does not call onClick Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

My issue is the page posts back but does not call the method.

Here is where I create the link Buttons inside the RenderProducts method

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= numberOfPages; counter++)
        {

            var pagingLink = new LinkButton
                                 {
                                     Text = " " + counter.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ",
                                     ID = "page" + counter
                                 };
            pagingLink.Attributes["runAt"] = "server";
            pagingLink.Attributes["class"] = "paging-link";
            pagingLink.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "true");
            pagingLink.Attributes.Add("AutoEventWireup", "true"); 
            pagingLink.Click +=ChangePage;

            paging.Controls.Add(pagingLink);
        }
```

The method it is calling

```
        public void ChangePage(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // handle this particular case
        RenderProducts(2);
    }
```

For completeness below you will see on PostBack I prevent it's default action

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetSideBar();
        BuildRefineSearch();
        PopulateList();
        PerformSearch();
        if(!IsPostBack )
        {
            RenderProducts(1);
        }


    }
```

Comment: try to add this in page pre init call and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved everything to the
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)

as this was a user control this solved my issue.

Thanks to [Chandermani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361151/chandermani) for getting me to think about when my event was firing.